# Why are `copy_from_user()` and `copy_to_user()` needed, when the kernel is mapped into the same virtual address space as the process itself?

Tags: kernel, drivers, c

Why are `copy_from_user()` and `copy_to_user()` needed, when the kernel is mapped into the same virtual address space as the process itself?

Having developed a few (toy) kernel modules for learning purposes, I quickly reliazed that `copy_from_user()` and `copy_to_user()` were needed to copy data from/to user-space buffers; otherwise errors related to invalid addresses resulted in crashes.

But if `0x1fffff` is a virtual address pointing to a user-space buffer, then why isn't that address valid in the kernel? The kernel is in the same virtual address space, so `0x1fffff` would be mapped to the same physical memory.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The address space mapping is the same on some (not all!) architectures, but even on architectures where they are the same, the protection levels aren’t. `copy_from_user` etc. serve three main purposes:

- they check that the permissions on the memory to be read from or written to would allow the process running in user space to read from or write to it — this ensures that processes can’t trick the kernel into accessing memory the process shouldn’t be able to;
- they allow for specific error-handling so that protection faults don’t crash the kernel, for example if the requested addresses aren’t currently mapped (think of zero pages or swapped-out pages);
- they ensure that the kernel doesn’t trip over its own protection, *e.g.* [SMAP](https://lwn.net/Articles/517251/) or kernel-specific address spaces (S/390).

Some architectures use memory layouts which allow these functions to take shortcuts, *e.g.* using a direct mapping of physical memory, but you can’t assume that to be the case, and it doesn’t handle all situations anyway (swapped-out pages aren’t present in physical memory).

Comment: Thank you. I have some comments. On `x86` and `arm` the address space mapping is the same for the kernel and process? The functions first disable `SMAP` before checking page permissions and writing/reading data? For architectures with direct mapping of physical memory, pages cannot be swapped out?

Comment: Even on x86, the address space mapping isn’t identical if KPTI is enabled (but that doesn’t affect user-space mappings). However AFAIK, user-space mappings are identical in user mode and kernel mode on x86 and ARM. SMAP is disabled only around the actual copies (look for `STAC`/`CLAC` in the kernel code). User pages can be swapped out even with direct mapping.

Comment: I see. I guess KPTI isn't enabled, unless one wants to protect against Meltdown, which few of us want in practice. Isn't SMAP disabled both for read and write to user-space pages; and their metadata (permissions/protections) can be read without disabling SMAP? Why would one want to swap out user pages with a direct mapping? In that case, there can't be more virtual memory than physical memory

Comment: Most distribution kernels have KPTI enabled. Permission checks can be done without disabling SMAP, which is why I said that it’s disabled only around the actual copies (reading from or writing to user memory). Why can’t there be more virtual memory than physical memory with a direct mapping?

Comment: I think the address errors I got while developing kernel modules were related to either KPTI or SMAP (it wasn't disabled before copying) then; thanks for pointing this out! I used Debian `buster`. With a direct mapping, virtual memory addresses higher than physical memory addresses would map to nothing (at least that's what I understand from the concept of a direct mapping: `X` maps to `X`)

Comment: Ah right, the direct mapping in the kernel works the other way round: there’s a portion of the virtual address space which is dedicated to mapping physical memory, so physical address X maps to virtual address X+page_offset_base (see [the kernel memory map for x86](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/x86/x86_64/mm.html)). The virtual address space isn’t constrained by physical memory, but physical memory is constrained by the amount of room which can be given to it in the address space (64TiB on x86).

Comment: But if there is a fixed mapping: *`physical address X` maps to `virtual address X+page_offset_base`*, how can virtual addresses greater than  `maximum physical address+page_offset_base` ever come into play? They are swapped out constantly?

Comment: Virtual addresses can map to physical memory, and they can map to other things (including page not present for swap or uninitialised memory). A single physical page can also be mapped multiple times. Basically, the mapping isn’t bijective. All the pages that are mapped into a given process’ address space are *also* mapped in the kernel direct mapping.

Comment: Excellent. By *page not present for swap*, you mean a page that has been swapped out to hard drive storage? A *page* is a concept of virtual memory AFAIK, e.g. 4K bytes, so are you sure a virtual address can map to a page (virtual address)?

Comment: A virtual address maps to a page table entry, and that maps to wherever the memory is — a physical page, a page on disk (in swap or a file), a zero page, etc. Pages can have varying sizes (see hugepages).